# Database backup download in sql format in laravel 5 without using packages

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have running live website  in which i  want to backup database in .sql format Without using packages.

Comment: why not export the sql file directly from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @BonishKoirala I don't understand what you mean, what do you want to ask? is there an answer?

Comment: Have you done migrate? `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: why not you are using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup this package.

Comment: in my server php admin is not installed. i have only access of ftp . so i want to export data by using code

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean backup database with php?
If you do, I think you can do this:

```
shell_exec('mysqldump -u' . $username . ' -p' . $password . ' ' . $database_name > $date . '.sql');
```

Comment: You can use this code to generate the file, and call the export function after finishing file generation.